# Multiple steps form (Wizard) with ui-router?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to build a multiple step form (wizard) with angular js.

As I understand, I have to map each step to its own controller and view (template). But it seems to me that if I do it then the model defined in each step view will be limited to the scope of the particular controller only.

Since I would like to submit all data filled in all steps at the end of the form, I wonder how should I code to make sure the model(s) is shared across all steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i would suggest to you would be to expose your model to each of the steps using a service\factory.
Each step can access the model exposed by the factory and updates that model. Your factory would look like something

```
angular.module("myApp").factory("Wizard",[function() {
     function WizardModel() {
         //Model Properties
         this.title="Test"   
     }
     var wizardService={};
     wizardService.model=new WizardModel();
     wizardService.init=function() {
         //instantiate a new model object wizardService.model={};
     }
     return wizardService;

}])
```

You can now inject this service in you controller. Before starting the wizard call `init` to reinitialize the model and use the `model` property to get the current model.

Comment: hi Chandermani, so when you say I cannot inject this service to my controller, how should I get access to the model within the controller?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. You can inject this service in controller :)

Comment: Thank you, just 1 last thing which may be unrelated to angularjs. If I assign within my controller say $scope.model = WizardService.model, then If the model on my scope changes does JS automatically changes on WizardService as well, or should I always set back?

Comment: WizardService is a singleton. As long as you are referencing the model returned by WizardService, any changes you make to the model, would affect the wizardservice model as reference is same. Also anywhere else if the same service is injected, the same model gets referenced.